# Language name of translated node

Tags: 8, theming

For a teaser view mode I want to display the language of the content. I can get the langcode in twig with: `{{ node.langcode.value }}` 
But how can I display the language name? In the field display I get only the string with "Language English", but I want only the name without any other thinks like "Language ...".

One way is to use preprocess node:

```
function mytheme_preprocess_node(&$variables) {
  $variables['lang_name'] = $variables['node']->language()->getName()
}
```

in the template file:

```
{{ lang_name }}
```

Is there a pure twig solution possible?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you want to use the method `language()` in Twig

```
{{ node.language.name }}
```

you have to add it to the whitelist of the Twig sandbox policy in settings.php:

```
$settings['twig_sandbox_whitelisted_methods'] = [
  'id',
  'label',
  'bundle',
  'get',
  '__toString',
  'toString',
  'language',
];
```

Comment: Thanks for this, it works perfect! So I can rewrite in the settings.php the 'twig_sandbox_whitelisted_methods' from the core/lib/Drupal/Core/Template/TwigSandboxPolicy.php and add other things like 'url' and so on?

Comment: Yes, you can do this, but don't add methods like delete().

Answer (score 0):

Use `{{ node.language().getName() }}` or `{{ node.language().name }}` (might not work).

With any object, like a node, you can call methods / get properties in twig by just using a '.' as the PhP ->.  Generally, getXXX() can be shortened to XXX.  Occationally, you may need to add a .value or .toString() on the end to convert from the format returned to string.

Here's the formal [twig reference](https://twig.symfony.com/doc/1.x/templates.html#variables) for this. The implementation notes give some guidance on how short names work.

Comment: oh sorry, i forgot to write this down! I tested it before For {{ node.language().getName() }} i get a blank page with kint() or an error page if i try to print it also for {{ node.language() }}. {{ node.langcode.getName() }} gives me the string "langcode"