# How to get node url/address from entity reference (content type)?

Tags: 8, theming, entities

Is there a way to fetch or print the `node` `url/address` from a entity reference to my twig template.

I have already tried `{{ related_links.entity.uri }}`, `{{ related_links.entity.url }}` or `{{ related_links.entity.path }}` but nothing seems to work

```
<div>

{% for related_links in node.field_pbn_additional_items %}

    <h2>{{ related_links.entity.label }}</h2>
    <a></a>

{% endfor %}

</div>
```

[image]

Comment: Rather than playing the guessing game, how about debugging it? Get good, [A: What is easiest way to debug variables in nodes, views, blocks and page twig templates?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/259037/what-is-easiest-way-to-debug-variables-in-nodes-views-blocks-and-page-twig-tem/259108#259108)

Comment: @NoSssweat already tried using `{{ kint() }}` to debug the issue but I just can't seem to find what I'm looking for

Comment: did you check available methods?

Comment: @NoSssweat is it under `Node` ? Sorry for my ignorance

Comment: You didn't read the answer I provided in the link above, didn't ya?  Anyhow, it's [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vhD9u.png)

Comment: Already checked the field that I was searching for in order to fetch the url/link of the entity reference. Still no luck or I'm just doing it wrong. I have searched the table and tried to fetch it using the following code`{{ <a>{{ related_links.entity.toLink.value }}</a> }}` or `{{ <a>{{ related_links.entity.toUrl.value }}</a> }}`  https://imgur.com/a/1y3O9kN

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No need to add the `<a>` tags, because Drupal will automatically create the link.

So just simply do `<h2>{{ related_links.entity.toLink }}</h2>`

You don't even need the label with `.toLink()` because Drupal will automatically grab it when generating the link.

The above is suppose to work, but I get an error

> Twig_Sandbox_SecurityError: Calling "toUrl" method on a
>   "Drupal\node\Entity\Node" object is not allowed. in
>   Drupal\Core\Template\TwigSandboxPolicy->checkMethodAllowed() (line 105
>   of
>   /home/ubuntu/workspace/drupal-8.5.3/core/themes/bartik/templates/node.html.twig).

There is an issue about this on drupal.org [Add $entity->toUrl() and $entity->toLink() methods to whitelist in Twig sandbox policy](https://www.drupal.org/project/drupal/issues/2907810) applying the patch in [#30](https://www.drupal.org/project/drupal/issues/2907810#comment-12378597) solved the issue.

Comment: Thanks applied the patch using curl. Thank you for your assistance :)

Comment: You can do this in `settings.php` as well, see https://drupal.stackexchange.com/a/259349/47547