# How do I print the variable "activeLangcode" in a paragraph twig template?

Tags: theming

I tried to get the value with (what didn't work):

{{ paragraph.activeLangcode }} 
{{ paragraph.activeLangcode.value }}

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Get the language of the paragraph entity through the method language() in a preprocess hook:

```
function mytheme_preprocess_paragraph(&$variables) {
  $variables['lang_id'] = $variables['paragraph']->language()->getId();
}
```

For a Twig only solution you would need to adjust the twig sandbox policy, see [Language name of translated node](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/259341/language-name-of-translated-node)

Answer (score -1):

Didn't work for me; So I used this method:

> {% set language = content.field_title['#language'] %}